# just want to know whether there is a possible data loss?

Tags: c++, file-io

I have written a piece of code which writes either to console or to a file depending upon the boolean value set by user.

The code looks like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    bool bDump;
    std::cout<<"bDump bool"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>bDump;
    std::ostream* osPtr;
    std::ofstream files;

    if(bDump)
    {
    files.open("dump.txt");
    osPtr = &files;
    }
    else
    {
    osPtr = &std::cout;
    }

    std::ostream& stream = *osPtr;
    stream<<"hello";

    if(bDump)
    {
    files.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here I am creating a std::ostream pointer and depending upon boolean value I am assinging address of either an ofstream object or std::cout. My only concern here whether the file operation like open or close are done properly or not. As I am new to c++ please help me out. Also point out if any bad programming practice is being followed here.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work like you wanted to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its correct and works.
The main thing I would do differently is [not to explicitly call close()](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/540/507) as this is done automatically by the destructor.

You can simplify your code slightly (and get rid of the pointer) with the ternary operator;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    bool bDump;
    std::cout  << "bDump bool"<<std::endl;
    std::cin   >> bDump;
    std::ofstream files;

    std::ostream& stream =  (bDump) ? (files.open("dump.txt"), files)
                                    : std::cout;

    stream<<"hello";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no potential leak. However, if an exception is thrown by

```
stream<<"hello";
```

then

```
files.close();
```

will never be called, but for your specific example of code there's no concern. ofstream's destructor happens to call close() for you.

Comment: In fact, unless your function is going to be running for quite a while after you're done with the file, `files.close()` is useless.  (The whole point of RAII is to handle stuff like this.  Trust it.)  And if the function is going to be running long after, i'd say there's a separation-of-concerns issue to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

You did everything fine, but there is no need for the `close()` at the end, because in C++ we rely on destructors to clean up for us, and `std::ofstream` has one which closes the file automatically.

You can also omit the `return 0;` statement at the bottom of `main()` in C++: 0 (success, really) will be returned by default.